# Kotlin Gradle Could not find or load main class

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I tried to copy the **Spring Boot Kotlin** sample project https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/tutorials/spring-boot-restful. I Added some more dependencies and when I tried to build the executable jar and run it, I got the error:

> Could not find or load main class...

*Gradle build script*:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3' // Required for Kotlin integration
    ext.spring_boot_version = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

/*plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}*/

apply plugin: 'kotlin' // Required for Kotlin integration
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version = '0.1.0'
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.Applicationkt'
    }


}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-quartz2', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-http4', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-docker', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-aws', version: '2.20.2'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Change `Applicationkt` to `ApplicationKt` will work, and BTW you may upgrade Kotlin version to `1.3.50`.

By `Applicationkt` I mean the one in this line:

```
attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.Applicationkt'
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin compiles the Application file in two different files:

- one file called **Application.class** with the Springboot things
- another file called **ApplicationKt.class** with the main method

In this second file is where the **main** function is located at, so you have to use this name in the build.gradle file.

mainClassName = 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.Application**Kt**'

Answer (score 2):

Update your build.gradle to

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.ApplicationKt'
    }
    from { 
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
}
```

with an upper case K in ApplicationKt.

This is required because of the way Kotlin compiles to Java Bytecode. The `fun main()` function in Kotlin is not attached to any class, but Java always requires a class and does not support classless functions.

The Kotlin compiler has to create a Java class. Because you already defined a class `Application` it created one with the suffix `Kt` for the functions in your Kotlin file `org/jetbrains/kotlin/demo/Application.kt`. You have to set this class so that the JVM can find it.

BTW a Jar file is just a Zip file, you can unpack it and see for yourself if the ApplicationKt.class is there.

Comment: I think the first two paragraphs are irrelated

Comment: Update the answer to explain why Kotlin does require the additional `Kt`

Comment: I changed the extensions to Kt and also upgraded the kotlin version to 1.2.31, but no luck. @phisch Can you try by yourself building a fat jar for the above project with additional dependencies.

Comment: I built a 'Hello World' example and it runs as expected. Please update your question with more information, especially the exact error message, the contents of your jar file (is there a class ApplicationKt), etc. Thank you.

Comment: @phisch Did you run ./gradlew clean jar command ? And after that you run the standalone jar file ? Can you try with the above github repository link ?

Comment: Yes I did and a spring boot applications starts. My build.gradle is slightly different though, see updated answer. We will need more details from you (see my previous post) to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have any success or are there still open questions?

Answer (score 1):

For me the main function needed to be outside the class body

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
class Application
(private val locationRepository: LocationRepository,
) : CommandLineRunner {

    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        whatever()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Kotlin create file `ApplicationKt.class` in the jar if your main class file is named `Application.kt`. You have to add the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.ApplicationKt'
```

If you use the classic `jar` plugin, you can do as below (which is described in previous responses):

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo.ApplicationKt'
    }
    from { 
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
}
```

However, my preference is to use `bootJar` plugin which is much clear and which allow me to use layered jars for example:

```
bootJar {
    layered() // Not useful if you don't want to use layered jars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One small (but easily overlooked) thing: Your Application.kt file has a class Application inside which the main function is present.

For example:

```
class Application {
    fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Instead, your main function should be out of the class:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // your logic
}
```

And now in your `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
application {
    mainClass.set("<package>.ApplicationKt")
}
```

should work